# Transform ith element of std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, stdtuple

Is there any simple way to implement the following pseudo code? Or do you go down a template meta programming rabbit hole?

```cpp
template <size_t index, typename Func, typename... Args>
auto transform(std::tuple<Args...> tup, Func fn)
{
    return std::tuple{ tup[0], ..., tup[index - 1], fn(tup[index]), ... };
}
```

Comment: @user17732522 the new tuple would have a different type in general, so that would only work in the specific case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the `tuple` using the template lambda and choose whether to apply the function based on the index of the current element

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template<size_t index, size_t I, typename Func, typename Tuple>
auto transform_helper(Tuple& tup, Func& fn) {
  if constexpr (I < index)
    return std::get<I>(tup);
  else
    return fn(std::get<I>(tup));
}
    
template<size_t index, typename Func, typename... Args>
auto transform(std::tuple<Args...> tup, Func fn) {
  return [&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::tuple{transform_helper<index, I>(tup, fn)... };
  }(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Eohq4Wvsn)

Comment: So this is new to c++20. Very nice. Now I'll have to figure out how it works :)

Comment: It actually reads pretty easy. But I doubt I'll be writing code like this anytime soon

Comment: @TomHuntington: Can be done even in C++11 (just more verbose). Template lambda (C++20) might be replaced by template helper function. `if constexpr` (C++17) has to be replaced by overloaded functions.`std::index_sequence` (C++14) has to be re-implemented,